# What is the smallest available Mosfet with basic functions?

Tags: equipment, airsoft

I'm looking to upgrade my ICS m4 but need a mosfet that is as small as possible since the room in my handguard is limited as is, and I don't want to reduce the size of my battery any further.

Which circuit should I choose?

---

Ideas:

> After some consulting with a fellow on our local [forum](http://www.airsoftsverige.com), I might try building my own.
>
> Here's a link to the site I found some rather good instructions -->
>   [LINK](http://unconventional-airsoft.com/2009/08/26/how-to-make-a-basic-mosfet-switch/)

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on [Electronics.SE] instead. Let me know if you want to move this question over there.

Comment: @MichaelMyers No need to move this to there, since I'm mostly looking for a commercially available system.

Comment: I think @MichaelMyers point is right your question is regarding a electrical circuit metal–oxide–semiconductor field-effect transistor (MOSFET) and this site is for Sports related question you can read http://sports.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: the question contains recommendations for an Electrical equipment.It may belong to Electrical Enginnering site

Comment: The question is pointed at airsofters with practical experience, even though the Electrical Engineering site might had me more scientifically correct answers. I am looking for input for a circuit used in this specific case, in an airsoft weapon.

Comment: @Marcus Putting more context into your original post would be appropriate.  It's better that sports-related questions look like such, and not like a question on silicon process technology.